# Laravel Request Method: PUT - Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, put

I have this error with the request ajax for the method `PUT`:

> Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

where is my error, please

PHP, controller PocController

```
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $post_edit = Post::find($post->id);

    $update = $post_edit->save($request->all());

    return $update;
}
```

Javascript in page:

```
            $('.btn-save').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var title = $('#titolo').val();
            var body = $('#contenuto').val();
            var id = $('#record_id').val();
            var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: '/posts/'+id,
                data: {
                    'id': id,
                    '_token': token,
                    'title': title,
                    'body': body,
                    '_method': 'PUT'
                },
                success:function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

And this is my form in Laravel 5.6:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycz3c.png)

In network console i have this response:

general :
Request URL: http://ajax.local/posts/1
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 192.168.10.10:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response header:
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 22 Apr 2018 12:08:07 GMT

Comment: There isn't one in your JavaScript - but you didn't provide your PHP code. So can't help unless you do.

Comment: Go and enter your developer console, go to the network tab and get the server error. Right now it could be millions of things

Comment: i have update the thread , i use Laravel 5.6 and have a resource controller PostController